# Segmentation fault when using array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

I am new in C and all this thing of strings is pretty confusing.

The objective of this part of the program is to split a string into multiple strings, in this way I can process the words separately.

```
 int SplitString(char * str, char * pieces[]) {
  int i=1;

  if ((pieces[0]=strtok(str," \n\t"))==NULL){
    return 0;
  }

  while ((pieces[i]=strtok(str," \n\t"))!=NULL) {
    i++;
  }

  return i;
}

/*****************************************************************************/
void CommandPros(char *str) {
  char *pieces[100];
  int numW = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    pieces[i] = (char *) malloc (100*sizeof(char));
  }

  numW = SplitString(str, pieces);

}

/*****************************************************************************/
void ReadEnter(char * str) {
  fgets(str, 100, stdin);
}

/*****************************************************************************/
 int main(){
  int fin = 0;
  char  * strCommand;
  strCommand = (char *) malloc (100*sizeof(char));

  while (!fin) {
    ReadEnter(strCommand); 
    CommandPros(strCommand);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But when I execute the program this message appear:

`Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: ... and when does the `while` loop terminate?

Comment: Use a debugger to find which line that causes the segfault

Comment: that come later, the program is incomplete my problem is the segmentation fault in the function SplitString.

Comment: What is `PrintPrompt`? And please provide a sample input that triggrs the promlem. Read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]

Comment: the problem is when the function is invoked SplitString. it never gets inside the function

Answer (score 2):

You should use NULL as a first argument starting from second call to `strtok`

Replace
`while ((pieces[i]=strtok(str," \n\t"))!=NULL)`

with
`while ((pieces[i]=strtok(NULL," \n\t"))!=NULL)`

Comment: Thanks!! very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Your `SplitString` function is overly complicated and wrong.

You want this:

```
int SplitString(char * str, char * pieces[]) {
  int i = 0;

  char *token = strtok(str, " \n\t");

  while (token != NULL)              // while there are tokens
  {
    strcpy(pieces[i++], token);      // copy the string, not the pointer
    token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");   // use NULL here, read the
                                     // documentation of strtok
  }

  return i;
}
```

Not directly related to your problem:

The `CommandPros` function is quite awkward: you allocate memory for 100 strings each of which has room for 99 characters (+ the NUL terminator), which is in most cases too much.

You should allocate only the memory you need. The overall design of your code looks wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the second strtok() in SplitString to below
  while ((pieces[i]=strtok(NULL," \n\t"))!=NULL)

The first call to strtok must pass the C string to be tokenize, and subsequent calls must specify NULL as the first argument, which tells the function to continue tokenizing the string you passed in first.

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to check the returned value from a call to a C library function to assure the operation was successful.  In this case, `malloc()` and `fgets()`

regarding:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
void ReadEnter(char * str) {
    fgets(str, 100, stdin);
}

int main(){
    int fin = 0;
    char  * strCommand;
    strCommand = (char *) malloc (100*sizeof(char));

    while (!fin) {
       ReadEnter(strCommand); 
       CommandPros(strCommand);
   }
```

There needs to be some 'consistent' method of terminating the loop in `main()`.  Paying attention to the returned value from the call to `fgets()` will do that very nicely.  Suggest:

```
int main( void )
{
    char  strCommand[ 100 ];

    while ( fgets( strCommand, 100, stdin ) )
    { 
       CommandPros(strCommand);
    }
}
```

also, the function: `SplitString()`  allocates another 100 parts of dynamic memory from the heap every time it is called.  BUT none of the code ever passes each of those (100 * number of lines in input) to `free()`.   This results in a massive memory leak

The function: `SplitString()` only sets a pointer to each of the areas in `strCommand` that were found via `strtok()`  and the expectation seems to be that each of the 100 allocated memory areas is expected to contain the actual contents of the string found by `strtok()`  Suggest:

```
int SplitString( char * str, char * pieces[], int maxPieces ) 
{
    int i = 0;

    char *token = strtok(str, " \n\t");
    while ( i < maxPieces && token != NULL )              
    {
         strcpy(pieces[i++], token);      
         token = strtok(NULL, " \n\t");                  
    }

    return i;
}
```

In the function:  `CommandPros()`  the local variable: `num` is set to the number of words found in the current `str` but is never used for anything.  The compiler will output a warning message about this problem.

Also, the posted code contains a 'magic' number 100.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis and they make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name then use that meaningful name throughout the code.